# Stored procedure called in VBA keeps going to default value for a parameter

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which I am calling from Excel. One of the parameters is a float, and it seems to not be getting to SQL Server. The results are fine in server and when I hardcode the query in VBA. I traced it in SQL Server profiler and it's passing in the default, null aka user didn't specify. What could be going on here?

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE um.topStudents
    @semesterStart datetime, 
    @semesterEnd datetime,
    @SchoolID AS char(10) = null,
    @gradeThreshold AS float = null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 20 
        sc.schoolname AS School, 
        sd.Last, sd.First, sd.SSN, sd.DOB
    FROM 
        dbo.StudentRecords sr
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.lkpmajor mj ON r.major = mj.code
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.tblstudDemo sd ON sr.SchoolID = sd.schoolid AND r.SSN = sd.SSN
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.tblschools sc ON sr.SchoolID = sc.code
    WHERE 
        r.StartDate between @semesterStart AND @semesterEnd 
        AND ((sr.SchoolID = @SchoolID ) OR (@SchoolID IS NULL))
        AND sr.major = '03' 
        AND sr.program = 'scholarship'
        AND ((sr.grade>@gradeThreshold ) OR ((@gradeThreshold IS NULL) AND (gradeThreshold >=3.0)))
    ORDER BY 
        sr.grade DESC;
END
```

The VBA:

```
Private Sub topStudents_Grades_Thres(semesterstart As String, semesterend As String, Optional ByVal gradethreshold As Double)
   'New ADODB Connection
    ....
    'New ADODB Command

    'With ADODB Command
        'use connection
        'open stored procedure
        .Parameters.Append cm_TopStud.CreateParameter("@semesterStart", adChar, adParamInput, 8, semesterstart )
        .Parameters.Append cm_TopStud.CreateParameter("@semesterEnd ", adChar, adParamInput, 8, semesterend)
        .Parameters.Append cm_TopStud.CreateParameter("@gradeThreshold", adDouble, adParamInput, gradethreshold)
        .CommandTimeout = 300
    End With

    'Open command with recordset 
    'Set range & copy from recordset

    'Close recordset & connection
End Sub

Call topStudents_Grades_Thres("20150701", "20160204", 2.75)
```

**UPDATE**: trying to figure out why parameters aren't going through to SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [UM].[usp_Test]
   @intParameter as int = null
as
BEGIN
    IF (@intParameter IS NULL)
      SELECT 1 + 0 AS [Test]
    ELSE
      SELECT 1 + @intParameter AS [Test]
END
```

The number not going through:

```
Private Sub TestSub(Optional ByVal num As Integer)
   ....
   .Parameters.Append cm_numTest.CreateParameter("@intParameter", adInteger, adParamInput, num)
   ....
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim num As Integer
   num = CInt(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1"))
   If ActiveCell.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Call TestSub(num)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at the examples, you probably shouldn't have @ in the name of the parameter

Comment: Like:
.Parameters.Append cm_TopStud.CreateParameter("gradeThreshold", adDouble, adParamInput, gradethreshold)

Comment: I see @ProvID referenced in your SP, but not defined as an argument.

Comment: what the heck.....that should be @SchoolID, maybe the browser didn't go through with the previous changes to the post

Comment: You're passing the dates as strings. How is startdate defined? If it's defined as a date/time that would be the culprit - you'd either want to convert your dates to date/times, or I think sending the date strings as "#" + semesterstart + "#", etc. will work.

Comment: Ok  I've just been working on checking the date parameters, I created the parameters as adDBDate in Excel. Now I'm just trying to get dates to pass in without an overflow error. 
Call topStudents_Grades_Thres(20150701, 20160204)

Answer (score 0):

Your VBA code is sending only 3 values (semesterStart, semesterEnd, gradeThreshold) as SQL Procedure input parameters.  The SQL procedure is expecting 4 input parameters; however, the missing input parameter (SchoolID) is defined as default NULL in your SQL Procedure.

You have to add ".Parameters.Append cm_TopStud.CreateParameter(...)" to your VBA for the SchoolID, and modify your [Call topStudents_Grades_Thres("20150701", "20160204", 2.75)] to something like [Call topStudents_Grades_Thres("20150701", "20160204", "123456", 2.75)], assuming "123456" is a School ID.

Comment: SchoolID and gradeThreshold are supposed to be optional parameters. In sql server I can run the stored procedure, with no schoolID supplied just gradeThreshold, and get the right results. Not in VBA for some reason gradeThreshold is not getting to the filtering.

Comment: ok got one parameter working, now I will look at the date parameters.
I used  param_Test.Value = testInt which worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I got it working! Changed to the correct data type and also changed the create append parameter lines from this:

```
.Parameters.Append cm_TopStud.CreateParameter("@semesterStart", adChar, adParamInput, 8,
 semesterstart )
```

to this:

```
Dim param_semesterStart As ADODB.Parameter
Set param_semesterStart = New ADODB.Parameter

With cm_TopStud
    ....
    Set param_semesterStart= .CreateParameter("@semesterStart", adDBDate, adParamInput)
    param_semesterStart.Value = semesterstart
    .Parameters.Append param_semesterStart
    ....
End With
```

Also plugging into "The Matrix" helped as well :P